# Perl script checking alpha numeric values in IF statement

Tags: perl

I am trying to check if the string contains * or ! then print the statement.
somehow its not going into the IF loop.

below is my code ,let me know if there are any syntax errors?

```
if(($dusers eq "*" ) || ($dusers eq "!" ) ) {
   print ("........")
}
```

Comment: `perl -c yourFile.pl` will check for syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen your entire code (you should always post your entire code, not just the one line you're having trouble with) but are you reading input from the user?  If so, there is a linefeed at the end, and that's why you're not matching.

So if you are doing this:

```
my $dusers = <>;
```

to get user input, you then need to

```
chomp( $dusers );
```

to get rid of the trailing linefeed.

If you haven't visited the Perl FAQ, it's well worth reading: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,i am basically reading the file for any * or !  and storing them in the variable. the script is not going into if statement posted above and is going to the else statement to print the error.
i can see the variable is holding the value '!' but still its not checking the IF statement posted

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to check if a string contains another string or is equal to another string? Your question says "contains" and your code uses "eq". Also, it's not a "IF loop", an if statement is only executed once, it does not loop.

Maybe you need `if ($dusers =~ m{\*|!})` but it's hard to tell from your question.

This will print the items that contain a star or exclamation mark:

```perl
#! perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $thing (qw(hey! star* nothing really? yes!)) {
    print "$thing\n" if ($thing =~ m{[*!]});
}
```

Output:

```
hey!
star*
yes!
```

Comment: I'd probably use `[*!]` for the regular expression. No need to escape the `*` that way; keeps it nice and tidy.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, this does make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I am trying to check if the string contains * or !

And your code is this:

> ```
> if(($dusers eq "*" ) || ($dusers eq "!" ) ) {
> ```

The `eq` operator checks that one string is ***equal to*** another. If does not check that one string contains another (which is what you say you're trying to do).

To check that one string contains another, you need the [`index()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index) function or (more likely) a regular expression match.

```
if ($dusers =~ /[*!]/) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, your code has worked  for me .